# replace for-loop with one line numpy code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Hi I have the following code and is there any way to replace the for loop with a one line numpy code?

```
x = 10
y = 5
z = 2
b = np.zeros((x,y))
a = np.random.choice(np.arange(y),size=(x,z))
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i,a[i]] = 1
```

With the above code, I get b as

```
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

I've tried `b[a] = 1` instead of

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i,a[i]] = 1
```

and it gives all ones in the first 5 rows.

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b[range(len(a)), a[:, 0]] = 1
b[range(len(a)), a[:, 1]] = 1
```

or for arbitrary value of `z` you can do it like

```
b[np.resize(range(len(a)), a.shape[0] * a.shape[1]), a.T.reshape(-1)] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have another doubt. What if the size of a's second dimension is not 2 but a larger number? Would it be possible to still generalize it in one line?